# How to increase file upload speed in winform application?

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, file-upload, webclient

The upload speed of internet is about 6 mbps. But when a file is uploaded from my winform application, speeds of 0.1 mbps to 0.3 mbps are achieved.I use  rest webservice to upload file.I send some parameters in header  and use GZIP compression to compress file before uploading.I am using WebClient.UploadFileAsync method to upload the file. So, what could be the reason for slow upload speed?It is not even near the normal upload speed.For the  uploads to different websites it is
about 6-10 mbps.Is this issue with my application or the webservice. As the internet speed is stable.

Comment: The slow speed is unlikely caused by the `WinForm` application more than the internet connection, unless the `WinForm` application is extremely busy that it forgets the uploading task.

Comment: Could this  issue be related to webservice?